# Java-Mysql - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql

I am using the fllowing code and get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I used several solutions from the stackoverflow. But the problem is not resolved! Please provide your solution.

**Inserts only once, but then I came across the above error.**

**My Java code:**

```
package DBConnection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        insert();
    }

    public static void insert() throws Exception{
        final String var1 = "test1";
        final String var2 = "تست2";
        final String var3 = "test.com";
        try{
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement inserted = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO wpsjim_target_sites (site_name_en,site_name_fa,site_address) VALUES('"+var1+"','"+var2+"','"+var3+"')");
            inserted.execute();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }finally{
            System.out.println("Insert Completed!");
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
        try{
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simjin";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "rootpass";
            Class.forName(driver); 
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            return conn;
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

*Update:* 
**When i use `e.printStackTrace(System.out);` display the fllowing messages on console:**

```
    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at DBConnection.Main.getConnection(Main.java:34)
    at DBConnection.Main.insert(Main.java:17)
    at DBConnection.Main.main(Main.java:9)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Does your db user use password or it is not using password?

Comment: Don't use `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` if you are struggling to debug, it only prints the message. Use `e.printStackTrace(System.out)` (if you actually need to print it to `System.out`; otherwise, `e.printStackTrace()` is easier).

Comment: Look here : http://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: @AndyTurner I use `e.printStackTrace(System.out)` and update my question.

Comment: @ArshadAli Yes, My db user using password. Mysql password is `rootpass`. The password has been successfully used for other applications.

Comment: Are you sure you can access the DataBase from your current IP Address? That might be the problem

Comment: @PekosoGarcia I am using xampp on localhost. Mysql db run in 3306. I am using phpmyadmin by this address: `localhost:8090/phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 3):

i think there is nothing in your code that will cause this type error, as you can see in error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

it shows that problem is with your user or password, so check once again that your user and password is correct if you are using password for database user.

Comment: The password has been successfully used for other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect username or password causes the problem.

Comment: The password has been successfully used for other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the default password is *null*. If you are using a *root* password it means you should have put like this:

```
String username = "root";
String password = "";//without space
```

Comment: I changed mysql default password. Mysql password is rootpass. The password has been successfully used for other applications.